# Open URL on table view cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, url

I want to open a specific URL on a cell click.

I am trying to do this using objects, but it doesn't work. The string 'url' gets (null).

Code:

```
//setting object
[self.url2 addObject:@"http://google.nl"];

//method to select cell
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Get your url, eg: NSString *url = yourArray[indexPath.row];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.url2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
}
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: why don´t NSString *url = [self.url2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; ?

Comment: Cause that returns a "bad access"- error

Comment: can you post all your code?

Comment: Got it to work by adding  self.url2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; in the top of the Viewdidload.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet,

```
NSMutableArray *URLArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[URLArray addObject:@"http://google.nl"];
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[URLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"URLString: %@",URLString.description);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

you can add `URLs` in `NSMutableArray` but make sure that
`URLArray.count == numberOfRowsInSection` to avoid `NSRangeException`.

Comment: See latest comment. It's fixed